# Exporting Google Forms Feedback Given to Student

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have given a Google Form as a quiz. Students have taken the quiz. I gave them feedback on the responses. Some were default feedback and some were custom feedback. I now want to create a report per student where they can see all of my feedback in one place.

```
for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
  console.log('j is ' + j);
  try{
    
  var rF = items[k].getFeedback().toString;
 console.log('The feedback is '+rF);
  }
  catch(err){var rF =''}
  var rScore = parseInt(items[k].getScore());
  if (rScore > 0) {
    arr.push(parseInt(rScore));
  }
```

The `items[k].getScore()` will show the score I gave the student. No problem.
BUT the `.getFeedback()` shows `FreebirdFeedback` and will not give me the actual string of feedback. With the `toString` or without it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. 1. Please include a [mcve]. 2. Instead of `toString` try `toString()`

Comment: 3. Also try  `console.log('The feedback is '+JSON.stringify(rF));` without using `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

When I saw [the official document of `getFeedback()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getfeedback), this method returns `Object — a QuizFeedback for the question item`. So, when Class QuizFeedback is checked, there are 2 methods of `getLinkUrls()` and `getText()`. In your question, I thought that `getText` might be required to be used. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var rF = items[k].getFeedback().toString;
console.log('The feedback is '+rF);
```

##### To:

```
var rF = items[k].getFeedback().getText();
console.log('The feedback is ' + rF);
```

#### References:

- [getFeedback()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getfeedback)
- [getText() of Class QuizFeedback](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback#getText())